# SSH login in case Remote Login turned off (via GUI), on same subnet (router)

Tags: remote-login

is possible (or some other way, another port, service...) login via SSH in case "Remote Login" is off (GUI - Settings / Sharing / Remote Login) on target computer, on same subnet (router - all ports are possible to use)?

What is happening from system command when you use GUI - Settings / Sharing / Remote Login? How it is done from terminal?

Thanks.

Comment: Please describe your computer (brand name and model). Also, please tell us what version and flavour of Ubuntu you are running (for example  version 22.04, Ubuntu Server or Desktop). Is the name of the GUI program, where to select Settings / Sharing / Remote Login `gnome-control-center`?. - Why are you asking this question: because you want to log in remotely, or because you want to be sure that nobody else can log in?

Comment: I installed `openssh-server` into my Ubuntu Desktop 22.04 LTS and `sshd` was automatically configured to run. Still (when opening `gnome-control-center`) it indicates that the remote desktop and remote control are turned off. But I could log in remotely via `ssh`. So if I guess correctly about your situation: ***yes*** it is still possible to log in. You must turn off the server, to prevent logging in. (I have never used the GUI way to control the ssh service, cannot answer that question.)

Comment: In previous versions it used to work with `sudo service sshd stop` (and `sudo service sshd start` to restart it). But I can't make it work in 22.04. I tried with `sudo systemctl disable sshd.service` and `sudo systemctl stop sshd.service`. All these commands 'seemed to finish happily' but I could still log in remotely. I had to use `ps -e | grep sshd` to identify the processID and then kill it with `sudo kill <processID>`. If problems try `sudo kill -9 <processID>`. Check again with `ps -e | grep sshd` that it is killed. That way `ssh` will no longer work.

Comment: I could restart it with `sudo mkdir /run/sshd` and `sudo /usr/sbin/sshd`.

Comment: I think it is not possible, because you turn off sshd service in case you switch Remote Login to off via GUI. I suppose in this case no other way to login ... ?

Comment: Well, I just tested it, and for that reason described what worked and did not work. I was a bit surprised. But I might not understand what you want to do and what you are asking about. In order for me to understand, *please answer the questions in my previous comments*, and also explain what you think is not possible (and if that is what you want or want to avoid).